# Populate 2 dropdowns from jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a change event that on it's own works well. However, what I am trying to do is, on the change event, update 2 different divs with using 2 different $.get calls to php. For example, user selects company name. This is stored in a global variable of `value`. I then need to query 2 different queries in mysql and place the results in 2 different divs.

I know this code is never going to workas is, so I need guidance from the experts.

This is difficult to explain so hopefully the code will shed some light on it. If you need anymore information, please let me know. Many thanks

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.rtvcompany', function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvcompany.php?rtvcompany=' + value, function(data) {
      console.log(value);
      $(".rtvdept").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $(".rtvdept").val('');
        $(".rtvdept").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your department");
        $(".rtvdept").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '.rtvdept', function() {
        value = $(this).val();
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
        $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvaddr.php?rtvaddr=' + value, function(data) {
          $("#address").html(data);
          $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            //console.log(data);
            $("#address").val('');
            $("#address").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your address");
            $("#address").trigger("chosen:updated");
          });
        });
      });
    });

    $(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '.rtvdept', function() {
        //value = $(this).val();
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
        $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvbox.php?rtvbox=' + value, function(data) {
          //console.log(value);
          $("#box_rtv").html(data);
          $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            //console.log(data);
            $("#box_rtv").val('');
            //$("#box_rtv").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your new box");
            $("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
 $(function() {
$(document).on('change', '.rtvcompany', function() {
value = $(this).val();
$(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
$.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvcompany.php?rtvcompany=' + value, function(data) {
  console.log(value);
  $(".rtvdept").html(data);
  $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $(".rtvdept").val('');
    $(".rtvdept").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your department");
    $(".rtvdept").trigger("chosen:updated");
  });
});
    value = $(this).val();
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvaddr.php?rtvaddr=' + value, function(data) {
      $("#address").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        //console.log(data);
        $("#address").val('');
        $("#address").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your address");
        $("#address").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
    value = $(this).val();
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/retrieve/loadboxRtvbox.php?rtvbox=' + value, function(data) {
      //console.log(value);
      $("#box_rtv").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        //console.log(data);
        $("#box_rtv").val('');
        //$("#box_rtv").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your new box");
        $("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but all get is spinning loading animation when i change the company. Also not populating dept or address with data.

Comment: It is also populating data from the company value in the dept and isn't using the data from php call.

Comment: send me all details on mail and i will try to help. i will be able to do more if i going to see all code and relations. i swear it will be private. my mail promotor.stron@gmail.com